# NodeJS + OracleDB. ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: node.js, oracle

Пишу модуль регистрации. При обработке запроса возвращается ошибка:

`ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

Фронт на Angular 5. 
POST запрос:

`createNewUser(user: User) {
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', user);
  }`

Собсна код:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cfg = require('./config/db.js');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

  router.route('/signup')
    .post(function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req)
    const user = {
      email: req.body.email
    };
    const unhashedPassword = req.body.password;

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      bcrypt.hash(unhashedPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        user.hashedPassword = hash;

        insertUser(user, function(err, user) {
          const payload = {
            sub: req.body.email,
            role: req.body.role
          };

          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }



          res.status(200).json({
            user: user,
            token: jwt.sign(payload, cfg.jwtSecretKey, {expiresIn: 3600})
          });
        });
      });
    });

      function insertUser(user, cb) {
        oracledb.getConnection(
          cfg.database,
          function(err, connection){
            if (err) {
              return cb(err);
            }

            connection.execute( `insert into jsao_users ('email, password, name, role') values (${req.body.email}, ${req.body.password}, ${req.body.name}, 'BASE') returning id, email, role, name into :rid, :remail, :rrole, :rname`,
              {
                email: user.email.toLowerCase(),
                password: user.hashedPassword,
                rid: {
                  type: oracledb.NUMBER,
                  dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                },
                remail: {
                  type: oracledb.STRING,
                  dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                },
                rrole: {
                  type: oracledb.STRING,
                  dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                },
                rname: {
                  type: oracledb.STRING,
                  dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                }
              },
              {
                autoCommit: true
              },
              function(err, results){
                if (err) {
                  connection.release(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.error(err.message);
                    }
                  });

                  return cb(err);
                }

                cb(null, {
                  id: results.outBinds.rid[0],
                  email: results.outBinds.remail[0],
                  role: results.outBinds.rrole[0]
                });

                connection.release(function(err) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                  }
                });
              });
          }
        );
      }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Тело запроса, кстати:
`body:
   { email: 'mail@gmail.com',
     password: '123321',
     name: 'Username' }`

Comment: Для начала попробуйте выполнить нужный запрос в БД что бы посмотреть что у вас с синтаксисом. `insert into jsao_users ('email, password, name, role')` ну никак не может быть выполнен, потому что список полей передан в виде одной строки в кавычках.

Comment: кроме того подставлять значения переменных непосредственно в тело запроса не безопасно. смотрите в сторону привязки переменных. И не понятно зачем используется returning. вы и так знаете значения, которые вы вставляете, зачем из получать из БД ... Максимум что может понадобиться это id, если его значение создается триггерами

Comment: @Mike, если правильно Вас понял - то вот:
``insert into jsao_users ('email', 'password', 'name', 'role') values (${req.body.email}, ${req.body.password}, ${req.body.name}, 'BASE') returning id into :rid``, но возвращается так же ошибка 
`ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
`

Comment: имена колонок не могут быть в одинарных кавычках. лучше вообще без кавычек пишите. И вам надо разбираться с привязываемыми переменными. вы там сейчас перечисляете какие то email, password но  при этом внутри запроса их нет а стоит явная подстановка значений вроде ${req.body.password}.

Comment: по хорошему у вас должно быть что то вроде `insert into jsao_users (email, password, name, role) values (:email, :pass,:name, 'BASE') returning id into :rid` и в следующем параметре, должны передаваться строго переменные с теми же именами, которые идут после двоеточий. Но я не вижу подходящих примеров в интернете, там почти везде параметры передаются в массиве, просто по порядку следования `["email","password", ...]` без имен

Comment: @0xdb Ну returning в переменную возможен. И наверное ее можно привязать. Но я не знаю будет ли оно работать

Comment: @0xdb `returning` есть и в SQL, причем не только в оракле, но и в постгресе заодно.

Comment: Ребят, без NAME запрос обрабатывается без ошибок.
Как только добавляю NAME - получаю ошибку..

UPD.: Поле NAME удаляю и в схеме Oracle

Comment: @0xdb Ну как бы вот: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2122356. Хотя что-то я уже сам засомневался...